# Time Format in Joomla

Tags: php, time, joomla

I am trying to input the time in 2 fields (From - To). Fields are defined in XML Joomla file.

```
format="%H:%M"
type="calendar"
```

When I input 24:00 in one of the fields, Joomla accepts the entry and inserts `00:00` in the db (fields in the MySQL db are Date-time). When I retrieve it back I have `00:00` in the field and when i save it back as is, it does not accept it.

Can you please help?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DATETIME Format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.
Have you checked the actual MySQL table?
Does it really have 00:00, or a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format?

I think it's the second option and Joomla does `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i');` to display your entry as `HH:MM`

If this is the case you should select the 'from' field and insert in the 'to' field without doing the `DATE_FORMAT` filter.